# Rails running with Unicorn: SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, unicorn

Rails 4.2

I run "vagrant up".

I have Virtual Box installed.

I am working on a Mac OSX 10.11

I ssh to the vagrant environment.

I start my app and go to the front page of my app. This is slow, but it works.

Then try to see another page in the browser. It takes almost 2 minutes for the page to render, during which time I see:

```
  ./bin/unicorn_rails
  I, [2016-02-12T23:59:43.291050 #20214]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=11
  I, [2016-02-12T23:59:43.291348 #20214]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
  I, [2016-02-12T23:59:43.293053 #20214]  INFO -- : master process ready
  I, [2016-02-12T23:59:43.297287 #20243]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=20243
  I, [2016-02-12T23:59:43.297441 #20243]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
  I, [2016-02-13T00:00:03.677384 #20243]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
  E, [2016-02-13T00:06:42.781557 #20214] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:20243 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
  E, [2016-02-13T00:06:43.051335 #20214] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20243 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
  I, [2016-02-13T00:06:43.074907 #20214]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
  I, [2016-02-13T00:06:43.259004 #20263]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=20263
  I, [2016-02-13T00:06:43.270408 #20263]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:07.999131 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.020710 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.020774 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.020798 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.020820 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.398987 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.399073 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.516064 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.564657 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.608567 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.656556 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.716912 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.770429 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.820702 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.872056 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:08.941071 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:09.010447 #20214]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
  I, [2016-02-13T00:07:09.977588 #20263]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

I have two questions:

1.) why is nothing logged to the terminal when I go to the front page? I'm used to seeing a lot of data logged.

2.) Has anyone seen this error before? "SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized"

Answer (score 2):

It happened because of terminal is resized after running

```
./bin/unicorn_rails
```

Here is link of issue ([issue link](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/449))